# Issues Installing yeoman on windows

Tags: windows, node.js, cmd, installation, yeoman

i'm trying to install yeoman on my windows vista machine

my version of node is v0.10.15
my version of npm is 1.3.5

i typed in the command to install yeoman globally

```
npm install -g yo
```

and i get get the following errors as below

```
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/yo
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/yo
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/lodash
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/nopt
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/yeoman-generator
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/insight
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/async
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/sudo-block
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/open/0.0.4
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/chalk
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/findup
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/update-notifier
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/shelljs
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/nopt
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/yeoman-generator
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/insight
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/async
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/sudo-block
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/chalk
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/update-notifier
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/shelljs
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/open/0.0.4
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/lodash
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/findup
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/has-color
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/ansi-styles
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/strip-ansi
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/request
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/configstore
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/inquirer
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/object-assign
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/lodash.debounce
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/has-color
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/ansi-styles
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/strip-ansi
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/inquirer
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/object-assign
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/lodash.debounce
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/request
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/configstore
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/semver
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/mkdirp
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/graceful-fs
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/semver
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/osenv/0.0.3
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/uuid
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/js-yaml
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/lodash.isfunction
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/lodash.isobject
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/lodash.now
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/mkdirp
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/graceful-fs
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/osenv/0.0.3
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/lodash.isfunction
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/lodash.isobject
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/js-yaml
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/lodash.now
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/abbrev
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/uuid
npm ERR! error rolling back Error: ENOTEMPTY, rmdir 'C:\Users\solidstunna101\App
Data\Roaming\npm\node_modules\yo\node_modules\lodash\dist'
npm ERR! error rolling back  yo@1.1.2 { [Error: ENOTEMPTY, rmdir 'C:\Users\solid
stunna101\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\yo\node_modules\lodash\dist']
npm ERR! error rolling back   errno: 53,
npm ERR! error rolling back   code: 'ENOTEMPTY',
npm ERR! error rolling back   path: 'C:\\Users\\solidstunna101\\AppData\\Roaming
\\npm\\node_modules\\yo\\node_modules\\lodash\\dist' }
npm ERR! Error: No compatible version found: chalk@'^0.4.0'
npm ERR! Valid install targets:
npm ERR! ["0.1.0","0.1.1","0.2.0","0.2.1","0.3.0","0.4.0","0.5.0","0.5.1"]
npm ERR!     at installTargetsError (c:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\li
b\cache.js:719:10)
npm ERR!     at c:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\lib\cache.js:638:10
npm ERR!     at RegClient.get_ (c:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_mo
dules\npm-registry-client\lib\get.js:105:14)
npm ERR!     at RegClient.<anonymous> (c:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\
node_modules\npm-registry-client\lib\get.js:41:12)
npm ERR!     at fs.js:266:14
npm ERR!     at c:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\graceful-f
s\graceful-fs.js:103:5
npm ERR!     at Object.oncomplete (fs.js:107:15)
npm ERR! If you need help, you may report this log at:
npm ERR!     <http://github.com/isaacs/npm/issues>
npm ERR! or email it to:
npm ERR!     <npm-@googlegroups.com>

npm ERR! System Windows_NT 6.0.6001
npm ERR! command "c:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "c:\\Program Files\\nodej
s\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "install" "-g" "yo"
npm ERR! cwd c:\xampp\htdocs\frontend_workflows
npm ERR! node -v v0.10.15
npm ERR! npm -v 1.3.5
npm ERR! Error: ENOENT, lstat 'C:\Users\solidstunna101\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_
modules\yo\node_modules\yeoman-generator\lib\env\resolver.js'
npm ERR! If you need help, you may report this log at:
npm ERR!     <http://github.com/isaacs/npm/issues>
npm ERR! or email it to:
npm ERR!     <npm-@googlegroups.com>

npm ERR! System Windows_NT 6.0.6001
npm ERR! command "c:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "c:\\Program Files\\nodej
s\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "install" "-g" "yo"
npm ERR! cwd c:\xampp\htdocs\frontend_workflows
npm ERR! node -v v0.10.15
npm ERR! npm -v 1.3.5
npm ERR! path C:\Users\solidstunna101\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\yo\node_m
odules\yeoman-generator\lib\env\resolver.js
npm ERR! fstream_path C:\Users\solidstunna101\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\y
o\node_modules\yeoman-generator\lib\env\resolver.js
npm ERR! fstream_type File
npm ERR! fstream_class FileWriter
npm ERR! code ENOENT
npm ERR! errno 34
npm ERR! fstream_stack c:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\fst
ream\lib\writer.js:284:26
npm ERR! fstream_stack Object.oncomplete (fs.js:107:15)
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/abbrev
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/colors
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/commander
npm ERR! Error: ENOENT, lstat 'C:\Users\solidstunna101\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_
modules\yo\node_modules\shelljs\src\exec.js'
npm ERR! If you need help, you may report this log at:
npm ERR!     <http://github.com/isaacs/npm/issues>
npm ERR! or email it to:
npm ERR!     <npm-@googlegroups.com>

npm ERR! System Windows_NT 6.0.6001
npm ERR! command "c:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "c:\\Program Files\\nodej
s\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "install" "-g" "yo"
npm ERR! cwd c:\xampp\htdocs\frontend_workflows
npm ERR! node -v v0.10.15
npm ERR! npm -v 1.3.5
npm ERR! path C:\Users\solidstunna101\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\yo\node_m
odules\shelljs\src\exec.js
npm ERR! fstream_path C:\Users\solidstunna101\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\y
o\node_modules\shelljs\src\exec.js
npm ERR! fstream_type File
npm ERR! fstream_class FileWriter
npm ERR! code ENOENT
npm ERR! errno 34
npm ERR! fstream_stack c:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\fst
ream\lib\writer.js:284:26
npm ERR! fstream_stack Object.oncomplete (fs.js:107:15)
npm ERR! Error: ENOENT, lstat 'C:\Users\solidstunna101\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_
modules\yo\node_modules\sudo-block\node_modules\chalk\node_modules\has-color\rea
dme.md'
npm ERR! If you need help, you may report this log at:
npm ERR!     <http://github.com/isaacs/npm/issues>
npm ERR! or email it to:
npm ERR!     <npm-@googlegroups.com>

npm ERR! System Windows_NT 6.0.6001
npm ERR! command "c:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "c:\\Program Files\\nodej
s\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "install" "-g" "yo"
npm ERR! cwd c:\xampp\htdocs\frontend_workflows
npm ERR! node -v v0.10.15
npm ERR! npm -v 1.3.5
npm ERR! path C:\Users\solidstunna101\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\yo\node_m
odules\sudo-block\node_modules\chalk\node_modules\has-color\readme.md
npm ERR! fstream_path C:\Users\solidstunna101\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\y
o\node_modules\sudo-block\node_modules\chalk\node_modules\has-color\readme.md
npm ERR! fstream_type File
npm ERR! fstream_class FileWriter
npm ERR! code ENOENT
npm ERR! errno 34
npm ERR! fstream_stack c:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\fst
ream\lib\writer.js:284:26
npm ERR! fstream_stack Object.oncomplete (fs.js:107:15)
npm ERR! Error: ENOENT, lstat 'C:\Users\solidstunna101\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_
modules\yo\node_modules\sudo-block\node_modules\chalk\node_modules\ansi-styles\r
eadme.md'
npm ERR! If you need help, you may report this log at:
npm ERR!     <http://github.com/isaacs/npm/issues>
npm ERR! or email it to:
npm ERR!     <npm-@googlegroups.com>

npm ERR! System Windows_NT 6.0.6001
npm ERR! command "c:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "c:\\Program Files\\nodej
s\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "install" "-g" "yo"
npm ERR! cwd c:\xampp\htdocs\frontend_workflows
npm ERR! node -v v0.10.15
npm ERR! npm -v 1.3.5
npm ERR! path C:\Users\solidstunna101\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\yo\node_m
odules\sudo-block\node_modules\chalk\node_modules\ansi-styles\readme.md
npm ERR! fstream_path C:\Users\solidstunna101\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\y
o\node_modules\sudo-block\node_modules\chalk\node_modules\ansi-styles\readme.md
npm ERR! fstream_type File
npm ERR! fstream_class FileWriter
npm ERR! code ENOENT
npm ERR! errno 34
npm ERR! fstream_stack c:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\fst
ream\lib\writer.js:284:26
npm ERR! fstream_stack Object.oncomplete (fs.js:107:15)
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/colors
npm ERR! Error: ENOENT, lstat 'C:\Users\solidstunna101\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_
modules\yo\node_modules\insight\node_modules\inquirer\lib\prompts\checkbox.js'
npm ERR! If you need help, you may report this log at:
npm ERR!     <http://github.com/isaacs/npm/issues>
npm ERR! or email it to:
npm ERR!     <npm-@googlegroups.com>

npm ERR! System Windows_NT 6.0.6001
npm ERR! command "c:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "c:\\Program Files\\nodej
s\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "install" "-g" "yo"
npm ERR! cwd c:\xampp\htdocs\frontend_workflows
npm ERR! node -v v0.10.15
npm ERR! npm -v 1.3.5
npm ERR! path C:\Users\solidstunna101\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\yo\node_m
odules\insight\node_modules\inquirer\lib\prompts\checkbox.js
npm ERR! fstream_path C:\Users\solidstunna101\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\y
o\node_modules\insight\node_modules\inquirer\lib\prompts\checkbox.js
npm ERR! fstream_type File
npm ERR! fstream_class FileWriter
npm ERR! code ENOENT
npm ERR! errno 34
npm ERR! fstream_stack c:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\fst
ream\lib\writer.js:284:26
npm ERR! fstream_stack Object.oncomplete (fs.js:107:15)
npm ERR! Error: ENOENT, lstat 'C:\Users\solidstunna101\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_
modules\yo\node_modules\insight\node_modules\request\request.js'
npm ERR! If you need help, you may report this log at:
npm ERR!     <http://github.com/isaacs/npm/issues>
npm ERR! or email it to:
npm ERR!     <npm-@googlegroups.com>

npm ERR! System Windows_NT 6.0.6001
npm ERR! command "c:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "c:\\Program Files\\nodej
s\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "install" "-g" "yo"
npm ERR! cwd c:\xampp\htdocs\frontend_workflows
npm ERR! node -v v0.10.15
npm ERR! npm -v 1.3.5
npm ERR! path C:\Users\solidstunna101\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\yo\node_m
odules\insight\node_modules\request\request.js
npm ERR! fstream_path C:\Users\solidstunna101\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\y
o\node_modules\insight\node_modules\request\request.js
npm ERR! fstream_type File
npm ERR! fstream_class FileWriter
npm ERR! code ENOENT
npm ERR! errno 34
npm ERR! fstream_stack c:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\fst
ream\lib\writer.js:284:26
npm ERR! fstream_stack Object.oncomplete (fs.js:107:15)
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/commander
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/lodash._objecttypes
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/lodash._isnative
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/lodash._objecttypes
npm ERR! Error: ENOENT, lstat 'C:\Users\solidstunna101\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_
modules\yo\node_modules\lodash\dist\lodash.compat.js'
npm ERR! If you need help, you may report this log at:
npm ERR!     <http://github.com/isaacs/npm/issues>
npm ERR! or email it to:
npm ERR!     <npm-@googlegroups.com>

npm ERR! System Windows_NT 6.0.6001
npm ERR! command "c:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "c:\\Program Files\\nodej
s\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "install" "-g" "yo"
npm ERR! cwd c:\xampp\htdocs\frontend_workflows
npm ERR! node -v v0.10.15
npm ERR! npm -v 1.3.5
npm ERR! path C:\Users\solidstunna101\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\yo\node_m
odules\lodash\dist\lodash.compat.js
npm ERR! fstream_path C:\Users\solidstunna101\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\y
o\node_modules\lodash\dist\lodash.compat.js
npm ERR! fstream_type File
npm ERR! fstream_class FileWriter
npm ERR! code ENOENT
npm ERR! errno 34
npm ERR! fstream_stack c:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\fst
ream\lib\writer.js:284:26
npm ERR! fstream_stack Object.oncomplete (fs.js:107:15)
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/lodash._isnative
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/esprima
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/argparse
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/argparse
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/esprima
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/underscore
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/underscore.string
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/underscore
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/underscore.string
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Additional logging details can be found in:
npm ERR!     c:\xampp\htdocs\frontend_workflows\npm-debug.log
npm ERR! not ok code 0
```

can someone please tell me what i am doing wrong and what i can do to rectify the problem that i may be having